# Dropdown not displaying in bootstrap between breakpoints

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navigation

I have a side navigation in bootstrap which I am converting to a  dropdown when window is resized. But between the medium and the small screen-size when the sidenav has to vanish and the dropdown has to come, for a few pixels nothing is shown.The sidenav also vanishes and the dropdown also isn't shown. Then after more resizing dropdown comes. I am using hidden-xs and hidden-sm classes for sidenav div and hidden-md and hidden-lg for dropdown.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm" id = "side_nav">
            <div class="padding-left-15">
                <h5 class="font-black margin-bottom-0 font-medium color-gray-dark">About Zenni Optical </h5>
                <li class="font-regular margin-top-15 color-primary font-medium"><a href="#">Our Eyeglass Production Story</a></li>
                <li class="font-regular margin-top-15 color-primary font-medium"><a href="#">Customer Testimonials</a></li>
                <li class="font-regular margin-top-15 color-primary font-medium"><a href="#">Press</a></li>
                <li class="font-regular margin-top-15 color-primary font-medium"><a href="#">Affiliate Program</a></li>
                <li class="font-regular margin-top-15 color-primary font-medium"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">
            <div id = "dropdown" class="padding-left-20-sm padding-right-20-sm padding-left-10-xs padding-right-10-xs">
                <div class = "margin-top-20-xs margin-top-20-sm"><span class="font-black margin-bottom-0 font-medium color-gray-dark" >About Zenni Optical</span><div id ="click_me"><span class="caret"></span></div></div>
                <div class = "margin-top-0-sm padding-left-10-sm padding-left-10-xs" id = "dropdown_nav">
                    <li class="font-regular padding-top-20 color-primary font-medium"><a href="#">Our Eyeglass Production Story</a></li>
                    <li class="font-regular margin-top-15 color-primary font-medium"><a href="#">Customer Testimonials</a></li>
                    <li class="font-regular margin-top-15 color-primary font-medium"><a href="#">Press</a></li>
                    <li class="font-regular margin-top-15 color-primary font-medium"><a href="#">Affiliate Program</a></li>
                    <li class="font-regular margin-top-15 color-primary padding-bottom-30-sm padding-bottom-30-xs font-medium"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
...
```

Can anybody suggest what could be possibly wrong??

Comment: Do you use media queries to interchange between the two elements at given breakpoints?

Comment: No I have not used any media queries as of now

Comment: So then Javascript is triggering those changes? Provide a link to a live example, it looks like we'll need to do some resizing of own in order to reproduce the issue and troubleshoot this.

Comment: Thanks @UncaughtTypeError ! But I got the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hidden-* use visible-* responsive utilities. In your case it is overlapping the default behavior.

For more information read documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

[image]

Comment: It worked perfectly!! Thanks a lot. I still didn't get the difference though.

Comment: Your Welcome.. :)  since the hidden-* will hide element for specific device and make visible for rest of the devices. In your case using hidden-xs and hidden-sm makes element never hidden across all device sizes. I hope it make some sense.